# Store: Customizing reports

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, ecommerce

**EE v2.4.0 - Build: date 20120123** and it is the **Store  1.5.3** module by **Exp-resso**

I looked through the docs and could not find a specified way to customize reports. Is there a documented way to customize reports?

**We would like to display the tax rule used to calculate the taxes for each order.**

*Just as a side note, if you ever have to work with eCommerce in Georgia, be warned that every single county has their own sales tax rate. Awesome.*

thanks!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately we're well aware of the county-level tax rate problems. Hopefully will have a better solution for this soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to change the reports available in the back-end. That said, all of the order information is available to you using the `{exp:store:orders}` tag, so you are free to create any reports you need on the front end. Alternatively, you could create your own simple CP module and pull order details directly from the database.

We're open to suggestions for how to improve this. Feel free to email `support@exp-resso.com` if you want to discuss ways to let users generate their own reports (or what you need to display which isn't covered by the built in reports).

Answer (score 2):

@Adrian Macneil would be the best person to respond, but from my experience, there is not a method to customize what fields, etc. are available within the current set of reports. There are also, no current Store extensions that customize reports, though there are for things like Inventory.

I've been interested in this as well. One of our clients operates a free publication shop. Many of the reports obviously reports on Sales, which we are interested in, but we aren't interested in total amounts in cost, but items, spread, etc.

I was planning on doing some custom queries, but it maybe doable with the API. In fact, in would be lovely if the API allowed people to just add report types and formats to the list of what's available.